# Why JQuery function works for only the first textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have two modal popup that I display at different time. Everything is same except the popup parent div ID.

```
<div id="modalNew">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Add Item to Your Shopping Cart</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            <label>Item:</label>
            <select id="itemChoice">
                <option value="Wine" selected>Wine</option>
                <option value="Shot">Shot</option>
                <option value="Beer">Beer</option>
            </select>
            <br /><span id="spanPrice"></span><br /><br />

            <label>Quantity:</label>
            <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="10">

            <label>Price:</label>
            <input type="text" id="price" name="price" placeholder="$10.00">

        </div>
        <div class="cf footer">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancelAdd"><input type="button" value="Add Item" id="addToTable">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<div id="modalUpdate">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Update Item in Your Shopping Cart</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            <label>Item:</label>
            <select id="itemChoice">
                <option value="Wine" selected>Wine</option>
                <option value="Shot">Shot</option>
                <option value="Beer">Beer</option>
            </select>
            <br /><span id="spanPrice"></span><br /><br />

            <label>Quantity:</label>
            <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="10">

            <label>Price:</label>
            <input type="text" id="price" name="price" placeholder="$10.00">

        </div>
        <div class="cf footer">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancelUpdate"><input type="button" value="Delete Item" id="deleteItem"><input type="button" value="Update Item" id="updateTable">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

The following JQuery which changes the `price` textbox based on the `quantity` textbox:

```
$('#quantity').blur(function (){
        var optSelect = $("#itemChoice option:selected").text();
        if (optSelect == "Wine") {
            var ftPrice = (parseInt($("#quantity").val()) * 9.00);
            $("#price").val(ftPrice);
        }
        else if (optSelect == "Shot") {
            var ftPrice = (parseInt($("#quantity").val()) * 4.00);
            $("#price").val(ftPrice);
        }
        else if (optSelect == "Beer") {
            var ftPrice = (parseInt($("#quantity").val()) * 2.50);
            $("#price").val(ftPrice);
        }
    });

$('#itemChoice').change(function() {
        //alert('Value change to ' + $(this).attr('value'));
        if ($(this).attr('value') == "Wine") {
            $("#spanPrice").text("Each: $9.00");
        }
        if ($(this).attr('value') == "Shot") {
            $("#spanPrice").text("Each: $4.00");
        }
        if ($(this).attr('value') == "Beer") {
            $("#spanPrice").text("Each: $2.50");
        }
    });
```

The above JQuery only works when the first pop up is displayed but doesn't work when the second popup is displayed.

Why am I having the issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id's in HTML are *unique*. That goes for everything in the DOM, visible or not. The two bindings you have target **an** id, which is probably the first one it comes two when traversing the DOM.

May I suggest you stop using Id's in this case and give them either `data-*` attributes, the normal attributes or class names, and query for them using these instead. For example as you have a name on the input you can target with that :

```
$('input[name="quantity"]');
```

As a side note, if the content has been loaded *after* the DOM finished loading (i.e. because an async event caused it to be there, ajax or another click event for example), you will need to bind your events to a lower level *unchanged* element and use bubbling to target the elements.

```
$(document).on('blur', 'input[name="quantity"]', function(event) { ... };
```

*An example using your code to work out cost of a drink (untested)*

```
var drinks = { wine : 9, shot : 4, beer : 2.5 };

$('div.modal-content').on('blur', 'input[name="quantity"]', function (event) {
    // Create jQuery element from the delegated target and 
    // work out data based on information in THIS form only.
    // ( 'this' in context will be the input element for quantity )
    var $delegate = $(event.delegateTarget),
        selected = $delegate.find('select').val(),
        quantity = parseInt(this.value, 10),
        price = drinks[selected.toLowerCase()] * quantity;

    $delegate .find('#price').val(price.toFixed(2));
});
```

I would recommend as per original answer that you remove all the id's and replace with classes as they are not unique.

Comment: Would that work even if both form have `quantity` as the n ame?

Comment: Yes, name attributes are not unique across the DOM, though they are supposed to be unique in context of the containing form. By selecting using the attribute selector `$(element[attribute="value"])` you will have a jQuery object with all the elements with that name attribute included.

Comment: But if I use the name attribute wouldn't it also change the other pop up value as well? Is there anyway to first check which popup is open and ONLY update the fields in that pop up?

Comment: Yes if you let it. Don't forget that `this` contains the clicked element in it's actual scope. `$(this).closest('form')` would only return the form it was contained in. One handler to manage all the forms due to `this` being scoped.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to show an example please... with my code preferably?

Comment: @SiKni8 added an example for you

Comment: Thank you. I just decided to go with one popup and display/hide divs based on the type and it's working like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jquery ON  or LIVE mehtod

Hope it will help you

thanks

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use another method as well

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the price id. When you want to update both the Price input fields simultaneously, use class instead of id. This way both will get updated using jQuery.

The input fields become:

```
<input type="text" class="price" name="price" placeholder="$10.00">
```

and the jQuery statement changes to:

```
$(".price").val(ftPrice);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use another method.